# Fastest way to match elements from two JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to explore arrays with JavaScript and I came across a situation where I want to match the elements from two different arrays.

First array:

```
json1=[{
    name:"abc",
    add:"xyz"
},{
    name:"mno",
    add :"xxy"
}]
```

Second array

```
json2=[{
    name:"abc",
    add:"xyz",
    off:"lop"
},{
    name:"rag",
    add:"vrt",
    off:"wwq"
},{
    name:"abc",
    add:"xyz",
    off:"lop"
},{
    name:"wal",
    add:"rot",
    off:"nim"
},{
    name:"abc",
    add:"ola",
    off:"blo"
}]
```

Both arrays have name values in common ('abc'). I am looping and matching each name value of json1 with each name value of json2.

In order to make it faster I have sorted the second array by name:

```
json2.sort(function(x,y){
     return x.name>y.name? 1 : x.name<y.name? -1 :0;  
});
```

I still think it may not be that useful, since if we have more data may be 100 elements or so in each array, it will take some computation time. Also to avoid blocking the page, I have delegate all these tasks into a web worker.

Is there any way we can make it faster?

Comment: `var keys = json1.map(function (e) {
    return e.name;
});
var common = json2.filter(function (e) {
    return keys.indexOf(e.name) > -1;
});
`

Comment: Since the second array is sorted you could employ any number of search algorithms to match name and add, reducing computation time down to a log scale.

Comment: If you're talking about 100 elements, then computation time is unlikely to be an issue. Have you benchmarked this to make sure it's really a problem?

Comment: @torazaburo can you please let me know why it wont be an issue, or can you refer a link from which I can learn. Thanks

Comment: The way you know if it will or will not be an issue is to benchmark it. Let's assume in the worst case you are doing 100 x 100 = 10,000 comparisons. Let's assume each comparison takes one microsecond. All the comparisons will therefore take 10 milliseconds--in other words, you can do all 10,000 comparisons in 1/100 second. It is up to you to judge whether that is an issue or not in the context of your particular application.

Comment: convert one to a hash?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care about the result of json2 after the loop you can use.

```
var match = [];
for(var indx in json1){
    var mainItem = json1[i];
    for(var mIndx = 0; mIndx < json2.length; mIndex++){
        if(json2[mIndex].name === json1[indx].name){
            match.push(json2.splice(mIndex, 1));
            mIndex--;
        }
        //this else is only used when you know that your json2 array is sorted ascendingly
        //by name property. this helps the time complexity.
        else if(json2[mIndx].name > json1[indx].name){
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

your matching results would be in the match variable.
m = length of first array, n = length of second array.
time complexity is (m + n) when json2 is sorted. 
worst case complexity is m * n which is when all records in json2 is distinct and json2 is not sorted.